# Можно ли в nodejs получить доступ к localstorage?

Tags: node.js

Можно ли в nodejs получить доступ к localstorage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Напрямую, естественно, нет. Но, используя, например, [socket.io](http://socket.io), можно легко реализовать.